# How to change message status in chat on scroll in reactjs? Fires too many events on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, onscroll, debouncing

I have been trying to change status of message on scroll in React js. For that I have used lodash throttle and debounce but it fires too much events on scroll. Can you help me with that? Examples would be great. thank you in advance.

```
  function debounce(method, delay) {
    clearTimeout(method._tId);
    method._tId = setTimeout(function () {
      method();
    }, delay);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
  if (scrollRef.current) {
    scrollRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
      debounce(() => handleScroll(scrollRef.current), 1000);
    });
  }


const handleScroll = (current) => {
let status = 'new';
let unreadIDS = [];
if (messages.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; status != 'old'; i++) {
    if (!messages[i].mine && messages[i].status === 'new') {
      if (current.scrollTop <= messagesPosition[i] <= current.scrollTop + current.offsetHeight) {
        unreadIDS.push(messages[i].id);
        // }
      }
      status = 'old';
    } else {
      status = 'old';
    }
  }
  if (unreadIDS.length > 0) {
    console.log('nnn: ', unreadIDS);
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
      "type": "change_message_status",
      "room_id": messages[0].room_id,
      "apply": "specific",
      "message_ids": unreadIDS,
    }))
    unreadIDS = [];
  }
}

         <div
          className="Chat-Messages"
          id="scrollableDiv"
          ref={(r) => {
            scrollRef.current = r;
          }}
        >
          <DragNDrop data={data} dispatch={dispatch} />
          <div
            className="dotsContainer"
            // style={{ display: 'flex' }}
            style={{ display: isTyping ? 'flex' : 'none' }}
          >
            <span>typing</span>
            <span id="dot1"></span>
            <span id="dot2"></span>
            <span id="dot3"></span>
          </div>
```

please help

Comment: You said it yourself, examples are great. Please show a little of your code, so we can understand why debounce/throttle are not working. They exist exactly for your specific use case.

Comment: I added the code